# To generate a specific pattern using numbers in python

Tags: python

I was trying to create a specific pattern in python but can't get the same output. This is the output i want

```
1
1 3
1 3 5
1 3 5 7
1 3 5 7 9
```

The code i have written is

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in range(1, 11, 1):
    print()
    for j in range(1 , i):
        print(j ,end ="")
```

The output pattern i am getting is :

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
```

what changes can i make to get the right output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just have to have a step of 2 and print the numbers so far at each step. The `end` keyword argument to `print` controls what it should print in the ...end. The default newline is fine as is. Default `sep=' '` is also what you need and so you just have to unpack your collected integers to print at each iteration.

```
from __future__ import print_function

xs = []
for i in xrange(1, 11, 2):
    xs.append(i)
    print(*xs)
```

I'm sure there's a fancier way to go about this, but this has the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can step over the range using last parameter.

You can try `for i in range(1, 11, 2):`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in range(2, 11, 2):
    print()
    for j in range(1 , i, 2):
        print(j ,end =" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output by using the following:

```
number_list = []
# N is the number up to, but not including, which you want to print
for number in range(1, N, 2):
    number_list.append(number)
    print number_list
```

If you care about formatting, you can do the following:

```
number_list = []
# N is the number up to, but not including, which you want to print
for number in range(1, N, 2):
    number_list.append(number)
    for element in number_list:
        print element,
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting odd numbers use `range(1,n,2)` and append the numbers to a `list` then build a format string like `'{} ' * len` where `len` is length of the `list`.

```
def print_odds(n):
    odds = []
    for o in range(1,n,2):
        odds.append(o)
        odd_string = '{} ' * len(odds)
        print(odd_string.rstrip().format(*odds))
```